My shadergraph animation gets extremely faster during in the actual game compared to the editor
Currently I'm using a shadergraph for an animated material, for some reason as long as I don't have any input it works as intended and with the correct speed, while if I do any action/input the animation becomes incredibly fast.
I already tried to use different types of times (deltatime etc.) and it completely stops working.


The Unity editor (in scene mode) only redraws the screen when it needs to. That means there's no "fps" and no regular rendering. Are you saying it works correctly in scene view? How about in play mode or builds of the game?

Not much experience with this, but I don't see CellSpeed() (or celspeed) in the documentation. Have you done a sanity check on the return value you are using to multiply time?
